# change directory command to desktop

Tags: command-line

when I open up the terminal and write the command

```
cd Desktop
```

also I have tried

```
cd /Desktop
```

a message appears that no file or directory was found what I suppose to do? I have logged in as  a root but still have the same problem any help?

Comment: about `cd` command http://askubuntu.com/questions/483129/what-is-difference-between-these-command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enter your user's Desktop directory, run `cd ~/Desktop` (the `~` is expanded into your user's home directory). If your Desktop directory doesn't exist, you can create it via `mkdir ~/Desktop`.

Comment: but I want to run a specific c document exist on my Ubuntu desktop if I make a new directory it will be empty

Comment: @arzeramade then you can drag the document into the terminal and then remove the "file://" at the beginning.

Comment: sorry but I am new to UNIX can you tell me exactly how to do this ?

Comment: @arzeramade What part you don't understand?

Comment: how to drag the document to terminal

Comment: @arzeramade Left-click the document's icon and hold the left-click button while moving the mouse over the terminal. Then release the left-click button.

Comment: did you want to open a document from the desktop?

Comment: but when I do this and then write the command ls nothing appears

Comment: @Avinash Raj : I just want to run a c document exist on my desktop

Comment: @RamchandraApte : I just want to run it

Comment: @arzeramade To run it, double-click the icon of the file. Ubuntu is not _that_ different from Windows.

Comment: @RamchandraApte : no I want to write the command gcc myfilename.c

Comment: @arzeramade Press Ctrl+C while having the file selected. Then type `gcc ` in the terminal and then right-click the terminal and select "Paste". Remove the "file://" portion at the start the text you have pasted and _then_ press Enter.

Comment: @arzeramade you may want to edit your question and add exactly what you tried to do.

Answer (score 2):

`cd Desktop/` Goes to the Desktop directory if you are in your home directory.

`cd -` Goes back to previous directory.

`cd /` Take you to the root directory.

`cd ~/Desktop` Will take you to your Desktop Directory no matter where you are.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in terminal,it will help you.

```
cd ~/Desktop
gcc yourfilename.c
```

Comment: Why sudo to compile? One link at random: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/42383-never-compile-root.html