# What is difference between these command?

Tags: command-line

What is difference between these command: I used `cd $HOME/directory/test/` before running each lines:

```
cd ~
cd /
cd ~/
cd -
cd --
cd /.
cd $HOME
cd $USR
cd
```

And all of these do the same behavior. What is difference?

Comment: please ask a single question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Eight separate questions, one per command? Having this *one* question seems better to me. Those commands are all very similar and do similar things. This question *is about why they all seem to do the same thing.* And there's [a good, thorough answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/483134/22949) that seems to answer the whole question, which is usually a clue that it really is in effect one question. On the other hand, we might find some earlier question to dupe this to...

Comment: @AvinashRaj: This is a single question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple command `cd <dir>` which changes directory to `<dir>`.

- `~` indicates `$HOME` directory
- `/` indicates the [root directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory)
- `~/` indicates the `$HOME` directory as well. The only difference is that it explicitly shows it's a directory (the trailing slash). `cd ~/` and `cd` and `cd ~` and `cd $HOME` all do exactly the same thing.
- `cd -` Changes the working directory to the **previous working directory**.

---

These special symbols "." (dot) and ".." (dot dot)***[Relative Parameters]***:
**The "." symbol refers to the current directory and the ".." symbol refers to the current
directory's parent directory.**

---

`$USER` and `$HOME` are [Environment-Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

`$USER` = The name of the currently logged-in user. This variable is set by the system. You probably shouldn't change its value manually. (ex:myuser1)

`$HOME` = The location of the currently logged-in user's home directory.(ex: /home/myuser1)

Recommended to use `cd "$HOME"` or `cd "$USER"` so-that `cd` gets proper input in case of space, etc.

Comment: @KasiyA  `//` is treated as `/`. So `cd//home`  is same as `cd/home`

Comment: @Pandya You may want to add information about what happens when you `cd` to an undefined environment variable. (The variable expands to an empty string and `cd` with no arguments is run, which changes to the home directory.) This may be what's going on with `cd $USR`, since while the `USER` variable is almost always defined, `USR` rarely is.

Comment: I didn't knew about `-`. Is this same as `..` then?

Comment: @Jack: No, they do different things. **`cd -`** takes you to the last directory where you were working in (given by `$OLDPWD`). It also prints out the old directory path. `..` refers to the parent directory; **`cd ..`** will move you one level up. If you were working in the parent directory before, `cd -` and `cd ..` will both have the same effect.

Answer (score 8):

```
cd ~
```

Changes to your home directory. `~` at the beginning of a path is an abbreviation meaning “the user's home directory”.

```
cd /
```

Changes to the root directory `/`. Nothing special going on here.

```
cd ~/
```

The trailing `/` doesn't make any difference. It forces `~` to be interpreted as a directory, but `cd` does that anyway. (A trailing `/` makes a difference on a symbolic link to a directory — compare `ls -ld /var/spool/mail` and `ls -ld /var/spool/mail/`.)

```
cd -
```

Changes to the directory that you were in before the previous `cd` command. This is a special case of the `cd` command: when its argument is `-`, it does this.

```
cd --
```

With most commands, including `cd`, the argument `--` means that anything that comes afterwards will be treated as an operand rather than an option. So for example `cd -- -P` means to change into a directory called `-P`, whereas `cd -P` passes the `-P` option (which makes a difference if the path that you change into goes via a symbolic link). When there is no argument after `--`, the `--` doesn't do anything; this command is equivalent to plain `cd`. `cd` with no argument, in turn, is a shortcut for `cd ~`.

```
cd /.
```

Equivalent to `cd /`, since `/.` is the same directory as `/` (`.` is mostly useful on its own, to mean “the current directory”).

```
cd $HOME
```

Changes to your home directory. This fails if the path to your home directory contains a space or other characters. [Always use double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters): `cd "$HOME"`.

```
cd $USR
```

In all likelihood, this does nothing because no variable named `USR` is defined in your shell, hence the command that runs is just `cd`.

Comment: I remember that in some cases (bash scripts) **$HOME/<Some Directory or File>** didn't work and I had to use **/home/$USER/<Some Directory or File>** instead. This is also true for **~/<Some Directory or File>** So there must be certain differences where it's advisable to use one and not the other (which I don't know) - am I wrong?

Comment: @KasiyA `$foo` outside quotes mangles strings that contain whitespace or wildcards: `\[*?` (and more under some shell configurations).

Comment: @Sadi In a bash script, `"$HOME"` always works to mean the home directory of the calling user. `"/home/$USER"` does the same thing only if the user's home directory is at this location (which isn't always the case on institutional networks). Unless you need to do something related to a specific installation's setup, `/home/$USER` is never right.