# Difference between cd / and cd //?

Tags: command-line, bash

What is the difference between `cd /`  and `cd //`?  We can see that adding `/` to the end doesn't do anything. But when I do `cd //` and `pwd`, I found:

```
$ cd //
$ pwd
//
```

What is difference between `/` and `//`? An `ls` in both directories shows the same content. Why is `//` needed?

Comment: What makes you think that `//` is "needed"?

Comment: When you ask why `//` is needed, do you just mean, why does `//` need to be treated separately from `/`?

Comment: @EliahKagan You are right .I mean if // is not different from / then why people created this

Comment: Also visit: http://askubuntu.com/q/483129/256099

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/` and `//` are pointing to same directory. See [repeated slahes in a path are equivalent to a single slash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1910)

> This behavior is mandated by POSIX and most applications follow suit. The exception is that “a pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner”.
>
> What you're seeing is not, in fact, Linux doing anything special with `//` it's bash's current directory tracking.

```
$ bash -c 'cd //; pwd'
//
$ bash -c 'cd //; /bin/pwd'
/
```

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and)

Comment: For a brief discussion of “bash’s current directory tracking” (although not directly relevant to this question), see [Strange difference between pwd and /bin/pwd](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146239/80216). **TL;DR** The shell keeps track of what *it thinks* the working directory is. This may differ from the truth. The best known examples are (1) `cd` into a symlink, and (2) `cd` into a directory, and then rename it. Apparently this is a third example, where the shell remembers that you `cd`’ed to `//` just in case that’s different from `/` on this system, without bothering to check.