# Difference between 'cd' and 'cd ..' in unix /linux

Tags: command-line

I am completely new to unix/linux OS. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS in my system.

What is the difference between `cd` and `cd ..` ?

I have opened a terminal and executed the following command: `pwd`.
It gave me `/home/avinash`

Now I executed `cd ..` and it gave me `/home$`

Then I executed the command `cd` and then gave `pwd`, which returned `/home/avinash/`

Can anyone please explain the difference between `cd` and `cd ..` ?

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/483129/what-is-difference-between-these-command

Comment: @muru. U have marked my question as duplicate and the link you provide does not explain the the 2 commands i have asked. And also the 2 questions linked to my question does not answer what i have asked

Comment: @AvinashReddy: [Pandya's answer](/a/483134/175814) explains both `cd` and `cd ..`. I edited the question to explicitly ask for an explanation of the former.

Answer (score 2):

#### Difference between commands

The difference is that `cd` is a single command, no arguments. If there is no arguments, `cd` will go to your home folder by default. Now, by contrast `..` always means "one directory up" or parent directory. So when you do `cd ..` it will go up one level. And this is always true, with exception of `/` folder, because there is nowhere else to go. Here's a demo:

```
$ pwd
/etc
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/
```

#### Using this knowledge in practice

So where are the two commands useful ? `cd` will jump back to your home directory, which is the same as doing `cd ~` or doing `cd $HOME`. This means that if you are somewhere very very deep in directory tree, you can quickly and easily go back to home directory. Here's an example:

```
$ pwd
/sys/class/block/sda1/holders
$ cd
$ pwd
/home/xieerqi
```

With `..` you can also do cool things.  Let's say I am in `/sys/class/block/sda1/holders` folder and I want to quickly go to up 3 levels. So we can do this:

```
$ pwd
/sys/class/block/sda1/holders
$ cd ../../../
$ pwd
/sys/class
```

What also can be done is to make [a function](https://askubuntu.com/a/703701/295286) out of this. We can navigate easier by specifying a number of levels to go up.  Here it is:

```
goup() {
    num=$1 
    while [ $num -ne 0 ] 
    do
        cd .. 
        num=$(expr $num - 1 ) 
    done 
}
```

Knowing that `cd ..` goes up one level, why not specify how many times we want to repeat `cd ..` ? That's exactly what this while loop does. And here it is in action:

```
$ pwd  
/sys/class/block/sda1/holders
$ goup 4
$ pwd
/sys
```

Answer (score 1):

- After execution `cd` you'll get into your home directory
- After execution `cd ..` you'll get one directory up in the directory-tree

Answer (score 1):

1. `cd` command will take you back to your home directory directly, its doesnt matter where ever you are.
2. `cd ..` will take you back just one step back, i.e to parent directory of current directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is one command, but `..` is a parameter of `cd`. Parameter `..` always means that you want go one catalog up in linux.

Command `cd` get you into your home directory:

```
root@test:/etc/init# cd
root@test:~#
```

Command `cd` with parameter `..` get you one directory up in the directory-tree where you are actual

```
root@test:/etc/init# cd ..
root@test:/etc# cd /etc/init
```

There is another parameter like `.` whose means that you always want go to current catalog. You can see this when you list tree:

```
root@test:/etc/init# ls -la
razem 248
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 lip 10 15:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 140 root root 12288 lip 10 15:07 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   338 kwi  9  2016 acpid.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   278 gru 28  2014 anacron.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3709 mar 16 04:05 apparmor.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1626 kwi 10 14:16 apport.conf
```

Like you see, always you have indexed on system file current catalog like `.`, then forward to catalog up using `..`, and then next catalog/files forwarded down in unix tree.